# Efficient Go serialization of struct to disk

Tags: serialization, go, struct, gob

I've been tasked to replace C++ code to Go and I'm quite new to the Go APIs. I am using gob for encoding hundreds of key/value entries to disk pages but the gob encoding has too much bloat that's not needed.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
)
type Entry struct {
    Key string
    Val string
}

func main() {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buf)
    e := Entry { "k1", "v1" }
    enc.Encode(e)
    fmt.Println(buf.Bytes())
}
```

This produces a lot of bloat that I don't need:

```
[35 255 129 3 1 1 5 69 110 116 114 121 1 255 130 0 1 2 1 3 75 101 121 1 12 0 1 3 86 97 108 1 12 0 0 0 11 255 130 1 2 107 49 1 2 118 49 0]
```

I want to serialize each string's len followed by the raw bytes like:

```
[0 0 0 2 107 49 0 0 0 2 118 49]
```

I am saving millions of entries so the additional bloat in the encoding increases the file size by roughly x10.

How can I serialize it to the latter without manual coding?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use protobuf to efficiently encode your data.

https://github.com/golang/protobuf

Your main would look like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
)

func main() {
    e := &Entry{
        Key: proto.String("k1"),
        Val: proto.String("v1"),
    }
    data, err := proto.Marshal(e)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("marshaling error: ", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

You create a file, example.proto like this:

```
package main;

message Entry {
    required string Key = 1;
    required string Val = 2;
}
```

You generate the go code from the proto file by running:

```
$ protoc --go_out=. *.proto
```

You can examine the generated file, if you wish.

You can run and see the results output:

```
$ go run *.go
[10 2 107 49 18 2 118 49]
```

Answer (score 39):

If you zip a file named `a.txt` containing the text `"hello"` (which is 5 characters), the result zip will be around 115 bytes. Does this mean the zip format is not efficient to compress text files? Certainly not. There is an *overhead*. If the file contains `"hello"` a hundred times (500 bytes), zipping it will result in a file being **120 bytes**! `1x"hello"` => 115 bytes, `100x"hello"` => 120 bytes! We added 495 byes, and yet the compressed size only increased by 5 bytes.

Something similar is happening with the [`encoding/gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) package:

> The implementation compiles a custom codec for each data type in the stream and is most efficient when a single Encoder is used to transmit a stream of values, amortizing the cost of compilation.

When you "first" serialize a value of a type, the *definition* of the type also has to be included / transmitted, so the decoder can properly interpret and decode the stream:

> A stream of gobs is self-describing. Each data item in the stream is preceded by a specification of its type, expressed in terms of a small set of predefined types.

Let's return to your example:

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buf)
e := Entry{"k1", "v1"}
enc.Encode(e)
fmt.Println(buf.Len())
```

It prints:

```
48
```

Now let's encode a few more of the *same* type:

```
enc.Encode(e)
fmt.Println(buf.Len())
enc.Encode(e)
fmt.Println(buf.Len())
```

Now the output is:

```
60
72
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RrRcgU-H8e).

**Analyzing the results:**

Additional values of the same `Entry` type only cost **12 bytes**, while the first is `48` bytes because the type definition is also included (which is ~26 bytes), but that is a *one-time* overhead.

So basically you transmit 2 `string`s: `"k1"` and `"v1"` which are 4 bytes, and the length of `string`s also has to be included, using `4` bytes (size of `int` on 32-bit architectures) gives you the 12 bytes, which is the "minimum". (Yes, you could use a smaller type for length, but that would have its limitations. A variable-length encoding would be a better choice for small numbers, see [`encoding/binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) package.)

All in all, `encoding/gob` does a pretty good job for your needs. Don't get fooled by initial impressions.

If this 12 bytes for one `Entry` is too "much" for you, you can always wrap the stream into a [`compress/flate`](https://golang.org/pkg/compress/flate/) or [`compress/gzip`](https://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/) writer to further reduce the size (in exchange for slower encoding/decoding and slightly higher memory requirement for the process).

**Demonstration:**

Let's test the following 5 solutions:

- Using a "naked" output (no compression)
- Using `compress/flate` to compress the output of `encoding/gob`
- Using `compress/zlib` to compress the output of `encoding/gob`
- Using `compress/gzip` to compress the output of `encoding/gob`
- Using [`github.com/dsnet/compress/bzip2`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dsnet/compress/bzip2) to compress the output of `encoding/gob`

We will write a thousand entries, changing keys and values of each, being `"k000"`, `"v000"`, `"k001"`, `"v001"` etc. This means the uncompressed size of an `Entry` is 4 byte + 4 byte + 4 byte + 4 byte = 16 bytes (2x4 bytes text, 2x4 byte lengths).

The code looks like this:

```
for _, name := range []string{"Naked", "flate", "zlib", "gzip", "bzip2"} {
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}

    var out io.Writer
    switch name {
    case "Naked":
        out = buf
    case "flate":
        out, _ = flate.NewWriter(buf, flate.DefaultCompression)
    case "zlib":
        out, _ = zlib.NewWriterLevel(buf, zlib.DefaultCompression)
    case "gzip":
        out = gzip.NewWriter(buf)
    case "bzip2":
        out, _ = bzip2.NewWriter(buf, nil)
    }

    enc := gob.NewEncoder(out)
    e := Entry{}
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        e.Key = fmt.Sprintf("k%3d", i)
        e.Val = fmt.Sprintf("v%3d", i)
        enc.Encode(e)
    }

    if c, ok := out.(io.Closer); ok {
        c.Close()
    }
    fmt.Printf("[%5s] Length: %5d, average: %5.2f / Entry\n",
        name, buf.Len(), float64(buf.Len())/1000)
}
```

Output:

```
[Naked] Length: 16036, average: 16.04 / Entry
[flate] Length:  4120, average:  4.12 / Entry
[ zlib] Length:  4126, average:  4.13 / Entry
[ gzip] Length:  4138, average:  4.14 / Entry
[bzip2] Length:  2042, average:  2.04 / Entry
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DNJNqtHeGT4).

As you can see: the "naked" output is `16.04 bytes/Entry`, just little over the calculated size (due to the one-time tiny overhead discussed above).

When you use flate, zlib or gzip to compress the output, you can reduce the output size to about `4.13 bytes/Entry`, which is about ~26% of the theoretical size, I'm sure that satisfies you. If not, you can reach out to libs providing compression with higher efficiency like bzip2, which in the above example resulted in `2.04 bytes/Entry`, being **12.7%** of the theoretical size!

(Note that with "real-life" data the compression ratio would probably be a lot higher as the keys and values I used in the test are very similar and thus really well compressible; still ratio should be around 50% with real-life data).

Comment: Impressive analysis (I always admire your answers) but in this particular case it seems like explaining rocket science to a kid who asked why his three-wheel bike is a bit slow. ;-) While I think `gob` definitely has its uses, for such simple task at hand the OP seems to have, I'm sure a straightforward reimplementation of what's already done in C++ is warranted for. Another upside of this approach is that the new code will be comparible with the legacy data they have.

Comment: @kostix That was my first thought and impression too about the question, but then I saw its last line: _"without manual coding"_... So that's why I decided to stay with `encoding/gob`.

Answer (score 4):

"Manual coding", you're so afraid of, is trivially done in Go using the standard [`encoding/binary` package](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary).

You appear to store string length values as 32-bit integers in big-endian format, so you can just go on and do just that in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

func encode(w io.Writer, s string) (n int, err error) {
    var hdr [4]byte
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(hdr[:], uint32(len(s)))
    n, err = w.Write(hdr[:])
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    n2, err := io.WriteString(w, s)
    n += n2
    return
}

func main() {
    var buf bytes.Buffer

    for _, s := range []string{
        "ab",
        "cd",
        "de",
    } {
        _, err := encode(&buf, s)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", buf.Bytes())
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/lGxo6a2IM0).

Note that in this example I'm writing to a byte buffer, but that's for demonstration purposes only—since `encode()` writes to an `io.Writer`, you can pass it an opened file, a network socket and anything else implementing that interface.

Comment: After your comment I even wanted to suggest to go ahead and post the "manual" version. +1.