# Convert int array to byte array, compress it then reverse it

Tags: go, compression, gzip, eof, gob

I have a large int array that I want to persist on the filesystem. My understanding is the best way to store something like this is to use the [gob](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) package to convert it to a byte array and then to compress it with [gzip](https://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/).
When I need it again, I reverse the process. I am pretty sure I am storing it correctly, however recovering it is failing with EOF. Long story short, I have some example code below that demonstrates the issue. (playground link here https://play.golang.org/p/v4rGGeVkLNh).
I am not convinced gob is needed, however reading around it seems that its more efficient to store it as a byte array than an int array, but that may not be true. Thanks!

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "compress/gzip"
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    arry := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    //now gob this
    var indexBuffer bytes.Buffer
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(&indexBuffer)
    encoder := gob.NewEncoder(writer)
    if err := encoder.Encode(arry); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    //now compress it
    var compressionBuffer bytes.Buffer
    compressor := gzip.NewWriter(&compressionBuffer)
    compressor.Write(indexBuffer.Bytes())
    defer compressor.Close()
    //<--- I think all is good until here

    //now decompress it
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(compressionBuffer.Bytes())
    fmt.Println("byte array before unzipping: ", buf.Bytes())
    if reader, err := gzip.NewReader(buf); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("gzip failed ", err)
        panic(err)
    } else {
        //now ungob it...
        var intArray []int
        decoder := gob.NewDecoder(reader)
        defer reader.Close()
        if err := decoder.Decode(&intArray); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("gob failed ", err)
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("final int Array content: ", intArray)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question, then? Just whether `gob` is appropriate or more efficient? Or do you have some specific problem with your code?

Comment: When I try to recover the initial int array after Gob->compress->expand->Gob I get an EOF - i.e its not restoring to the original int array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [`bufio.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Writer) which–as its name implies–*buffers* bytes written to it. This means if you're using it, you have to *flush* it to make sure buffered data makes its way to the underlying writer:

```
writer := bufio.NewWriter(&indexBuffer)
encoder := gob.NewEncoder(writer)
if err := encoder.Encode(arry); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if err := writer.Flush(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Although the use of `bufio.Writer` is completely unnecessary as you're already writing to an in-memory buffer ([`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer)), so just skip that, and write directly to `bytes.Buffer` (and so you don't even have to flush):

```
var indexBuffer bytes.Buffer
encoder := gob.NewEncoder(&indexBuffer)
if err := encoder.Encode(arry); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

The next error is how you close the gzip stream:

```
defer compressor.Close()
```

This deferred closing will only happen when the enclosing function (the `main()` function) returns, not a second earlier. But by that time you already wanted to read the zipped data, but that might still sit in an internal cache of [`gzip.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/#Writer), and not in `compressionBuffer`, so you obviously can't read the compressed data from `compressionBuffer`. Close the gzip stream without using `defer`:

```
if err := compressor.Close(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

With these changes, you program runs and outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/aT8KiEQXQG7)):

```
byte array before unzipping:  [31 139 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 226 249 223 200 196 200 244 191 137 129 145 133 129 129 243 127 19 3 43 19 11 27 7 23 32 0 0 255 255 110 125 126 12 23 0 0 0]
final int Array content:  [1 2 3 4 5]
```

<sup>As a side note: `buf := bytes.NewBuffer(compressionBuffer.Bytes())` – this `buf` is also completely unnecessary, you can just start decoding `compressionBuffer` itself, you can read data from it that was previously written to it.</sup>

As you might have noticed, the compressed data is much larger than the initial, compressed data. There are several reasons: both [`encoding/gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) and [`compress/gzip`](https://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/) streams have significant overhead, and they (may) only make input smaller on a larger scale (5 int numbers don't qualify to this).

Please check related question: [Efficient Go serialization of struct to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618399/efficient-go-serialization-of-struct-to-disk/37620399#37620399)

For small arrays, you may also consider [variable-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_code), see [`binary.PutVarint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#PutVarint).

Comment: excellent thanks alot. Reading about flush now, but will remove the writer from the process.
Edit: Is there a way to know when compression becomes valuable? And is using gob necessary to save a []int that is not worth compressing?

Comment: @amlwwalker When it becomes "valueable": measure. It depends on the input. Some input may be compressed better. The `gob` is not necessary, actually it just ads both computational and spatial overhead. If you still want to compress, just use `encoding/binary` to convert integers to bytes (which you can write to the `gzip` stream). Also note that you should not use `int` as its size depends on the architecture, but instead fix-sized integers like `int32` or `int64`.

Comment: Cool, so getting rid of gob then sounds like a good idea. I think I'm pretty close, its using encoding/binary to convert it back to the []int64 after compression that is failing for me - I get an empty array after reading into the []int64. Any chance you can take a look? https://play.golang.org/p/NRimlw4Udss

Comment: hmm issue maybe I need to know the size of the array first? gob can handle that? encoding/binary cant? - EDIT - yes this seems to be it. Hmmm. Does that mean I need to persist the length of the original []int64 then or can it be "worked out" on the fly? https://play.golang.org/p/cayXw7fCcK2

Comment: @amlwwalker Length of a value of type `[]int64` is not fixed, so you have to persist the length yourself. `gob` takes care of that for you.

Comment: Thats the ticket then. Save overhead by not using gob, and just persist the length. Thanks for all your help